# Users can't login after migrating to new server

Tags: login, migration

I am setting up a new Ubuntu Server 13.10 and copied over the user passwords and home directories from my old server (12.10) following the instructions I found [here](http://landofthefreeish.com/linux/how-to-move-or-migrate-linux-user-accounts/). Unfortunately now I can't login to my new server using their existing passwords. I see the users when I run `members users | grep username`. Any help on what I have to do to correct this would be much appreciated.

Update 3/20:
OK, here's an update. Yes, I could only login using my sudo password I created when installing Server. When I did a "members users" I did see all my users, but none of there passwords worked. And now to the funny (sad) part. I could see the shadow file did not match the one on the old server. To make a long story short, I managed to so hose passwd & shadow I couldn't even log in using recovery mode. I was able to boot with PartedMagic and took copies of passwd, shadow,group, and gshadow off of my current working server (12.10) and just copied them into /etc, no crazy awk commands like in the link I sighted. On reboot I can login OK and also checked several users and they work now??? My concern is was it OK to just copy the four files? Will I run into troubles with groups or UIDs which I'm not familiar with down the road?

Also when booting into recovery mode do you still need a functioning passwd file with at least one admin password? I thought the root you were getting was like a live CD where i could then add myself. Instead I was getting an error message about an unknown uid I think and I couldnt login. Thanx again if someone can give me insight into this.

P.S. - I should add I changed the values on the commands from the site to 1000 & 29999 respectively.

Comment: Do you have root access on the new server? Can you set up one user password and see if you can login?

Comment: Do anyone know if the password hashing algorithm changed between 12.10 and 13.10? That could explain the thing.